# SSD Slow Program Starts

Tags: windows, ssd

I just installed a new SSD in my laptop, and it was working really well, but now when I start some programs (and even use git commands from the console) there is a 10 second delay before anything happens. I am runnning a Samsung 850 Pro SSD, with an Intel i7 and 16GB of memory. I have also already disabled indexing, and the drive is not full. Also, I have made sure that the drivers are up to date. Please help!

Comment: That's pretty odd. Can't say I've experienced the same behavior on my laptop, which had a Samsung SSD 850 PRO retrofitted to it. Task Manager and Resource Monitor could help in pinpointing the issue.

Comment: Thing is, I am not seeing any processes that are using up a ton of disk usage. I am absolutely flummoxed.

Comment: try disabling your antivirus, and retesting. how much do you mean by "a ton"? is it read or write? if you use filemon or procmon, are there specific files involved?